# Usage of kotlin generics "in", "out" in inheritance

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have base class which I'm planning to use for downloading some data from server:

```
abstract class Processor<out T : BaseEntity> {
   fun loadData() {
      val data = fetchFromBackend()
      saveData(data)
   }

   // here I'll define specific logic of saving data
   // and here is my Error Type parameter T is declared as 'out' but occurs in 'invariant' position in type T
   abstract protected open fun saveData(data: T)

}
```

Then I have multiple implementation of this `Processor` class and use them like that

```
val processor: EntityProcessor<BaseEntity> = when(type){
               TypeA -> ProcessorImplementationA(...)
               TypeB -> ProcessorImplementationB(...)
               TypeC -> ProcessorImplementationC(...)
```

To be able to safely assign implementation of processor to base type I'm using **out** in `T` generic declaration. But this causes the problem in `saveData(data: T)` method. If I use invariance, means no keyword before generic declaration I will not be able to safely assign implementation of `Processor` to base type

Is there a way to implement this class hierarchy without class cast, or what is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this give you what you want?

```
abstract class Processor<T : BaseEntity> {...}

val processor: EntityProcessor<out BaseEntity> = ...
```

Comment: Thanks that worked!
Could you explain how `in` `out` work in declaration of variable?

Comment: It's explained in https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#use-site-variance-type-projections. Here you will be able to call `processor.loadData()` (which doesn't involve `T`), but not `processor.saveData(something)` because it has `T` in the wrong position, so the compiler doesn't know which type `something` has to be.